# Generic List Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the part of the code where I create a second form on a button click.

```
private List<Team> Teams = new List<Team>();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form Form2 = new Form2(Teams);
     Form2.Show();
}
```

Form 2:

```
public Form2(List<Team> teams)
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

And I'm always getting back this error:

> Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Projekt.Team>`' is less accessible
>   than method
>   '`Projekt.Form2.Form2(System.Collections.Generic.List<Projekt.Team>)`'

Comment: What is the declaration of Team and Csapat? It seems that Team is less accessible.

Comment: Try to make Team public, or at least internal

Comment: sorry Csapat was just a typo i updated the original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Team` is most likely `internal`, so it can't appear in the signature of a `public` method on a `public` class.

You can either make `Team` public or the method `private`/`internal`.

Answer (score 2):

`Team` should be made public. The `Form` constructor is public but it needs a parameter that's not public.