# Inconsistent accessibility when I try to rebuild it

Tags: c#

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: base class
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' is
>   less accessible than class 'LPC.BusinessObjects.Employeelist'

```
public class Employeelist : List<Employee>
{
    public static Employeelist GetEmployees()
    {
        Employeelist el = null;
        el = EmployeeDalc.GetEmployees();
        return el;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the Employee class as Public 
** public Employee
{
   public Employee()
{
}
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic List Inconsistent accessibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345040/generic-list-inconsistent-accessibility)

Comment: This is a namespace issue.

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of the above.  In your case, `Employee` is probably not marked as `public`

Comment: @RvdK: Its factory pattern (ish) - GetEmployees is a static method.

Comment: @JonEgerton: a overlooked the static part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting it to `public` is like putting a `try catch` over the entire app because there is an exception.

There are a few things to consider:

1. Did you author this class? If yes, then you need to identify the lowest level of accessibility that it can have. Perhaps it is `public`, but maybe `internal` will work?
2. If you didnt, there is probably a reason that the author chose that level of accessibility so you need to relook at how you are using the class.

Comment: when i change some part into public i get this:

Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'LPC.BusinessObjects.Employeelist' is less accessible than method 'LPC.BusinessObjects.EmployeeDalc.GetEmployees()'

Answer (score 0):

The class `Employee` is probably defined as `private` or `protected`, fix it to be `public`. That'll do it.